Packing, unpacking and storing parameter pack in a tuple
I have a function pointer and parameters, and I'd like to save these and potentially modify them and call the function with them.
I've seen parts of this answered however I'm unsure how a complete solution would look like, I apologize, but I don't really understand parameter packs, and how they relate to tuple.
Here's bits of my code that I'm trying to make work together:
I have this which is basically just calling the function, I think this can be used to save the call into the "callable" structure, to make an interface.
from this question:
C++ generic function call with varargs parameter
template<typename R, typename... Args>
auto call(R(*function)(Args...), Args... args) -> typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<R, void>::value, R>::type 
{
    return function(args...);
}

template<typename... Args>
void call(void (*function)(Args...), Args... args)
{
    function(args...);
}

This structure should store the parameters and the function pointer. (thanks to RaymondChen for pointing out how it should be correctly)
template<typename R, typename... Args>
struct callable
{
    R(*function)(Args...);
    std::tuple<Args...> params;

    callable(Args... argv):
    params(std::make_tuple(argv...))
    {}

    // .....
};

I'm still unsure how to call back the function with the std::tuple. As far as I understand I should somehow turn the tuple back to Args... and then call it.
**What I'm trying to achieve: 

Save a call to be used later on
Create my call and fill it with my parameters, from a running app.
Read out saved parameters to do some manner of debugging.**


Still unclear what you are trying to do since std::apply(argv, params) makes no sense. The params member doesn't contain anything yet.) Is constructing the callable support to call the function or just save the parameters? If saving, then callable(Args...argv) : params(std::make_tuple(argv...)) {}

How do you want to use callable?  Raymond has shown how to store argv into params.  How do you intend to have callable call the function?

@NathanOliver I'd like to simply call a function that returns the functions type but has no parameters as those are in callable, so like auto call(), or perhaps with void* as return type, which would then call callable->function. idk how I'd apply the parameters tho.

I've figured it out, it's literally the std::apply(function, params) the last piece of the puzzle is to make a constructor that takes only the function pointer, so that I can provide the parameters my self. Or perhaps I should separate the parameters and the function pointer and only store the parameters when actually needed.

Isn't std::function enough/simpler?

@Jarod42 no, while here everything is in a small struct, in my final code fn pointers and parameters are stored separately in vectors. This is for cache coherence purposes, as well as to allow me to read/reuse/modify parameters for "Just in time" optimization.

If you have started storing the function and required parameters for it in the Callable, I would suggest just provide a operator() overload for calling the Callable with its stored parameters.
Something along the line:
// Functor to store the function and its parameters
template<typename R, typename... Args>
class Callable /* final */
{
    R(*mFuncPtr)(Args...) { nullptr };  //  function pointer.
    std::tuple<Args...> mParams{};      //  store the parameters as std::tuple

public:
    explicit constexpr Callable(R(*func)(Args...))
        : mFuncPtr{ func } {}

    explicit constexpr Callable(R(*func)(Args...), Args&&... argv)
        : mFuncPtr{ func }
        , mParams{ std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(argv)...) } {}

    // optional setter for mParams
    void set(Args&&... argv)
    {
        mParams = std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(argv)...);
    }

    auto operator()() -> std::conditional_t<std::is_void_v<R>, void*, R>
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_void_v<R>) 
        {  
            // invoke the function pointer with tuple pack. 
            std::apply(mFuncPtr, mParams);
            return nullptr;     // Use nullptr for void return type
        }
        else 
        {
            return std::apply(mFuncPtr, mParams);;
        }
    }

    // Print the stored parameters
    void printParams() const
    {
        std::cout << "(";
        printParamsImpl(std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});
        std::cout << ")\n";
    }

private:
    template<std::size_t... I>
    void printParamsImpl(std::index_sequence<I...>) const
    {
        (..., (std::cout << (I == 0 ? "" : ", ") << std::get<I>(mParams)));
    }
};

(See live example demo)

I like how you don't need to specify the template types explicitly, however that breaks when the function is void fn(void) I've modified the example to highlight it: example I think type_traits could help with that, but I'm not sure how I could use that, perhaps there could be a 0 parameter specialization?

why are you returning a null void* in the void case? You can return std::apply(mFuncPtr, mParams); unconditionally: "In a function returning (possibly cv-qualified) void, the return statement with expression can be used, if the expression type is (possibly cv-qualified) void." https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return

@Caleth As OP mentioned in the comment under the post: "[...] like auto call(), or perhaps with void* as return type, which would then call callable->function [...]". I assume, then he/she meant as I posted, which was also accepted BTW. Why he/she wants so,... that is a different ques!

Again I should state that less is more. The std::bind library function already handles this problem pretty efficiently:
template<typename... Args>
//requires sizeof...(Args) > 1
using Callable = decltype(std::bind(std::declval<Args>()...);

Callable c = std::bind(&foo::x,y,z,w);
auto res = c();

To further reinforce the design add std::function to your mix:
template<typename R,typename... Args>
using Call_in = Callable<std::function<R(Args...)>, Args...>;

Call_in ci=std::bind(std::function<foo(bar)>{&bar::x}, bar{});
foo resi = ci();

This one is more dynamic; it can type erase the function [object] argument, so that all functions with similar call signature can be stored using same specialization.

How does this let me read out specific values from parameters? How does it let me separate function pointer from parameters? For my usecase I need to have access to this data, as far as I can see std::bind doesn't let you do this.

@LemonJumps if that's the case, why bother with encapsulation and constructors?
template<typename R,typename ...A> struct voidfn{     std::function<R(A...)> fn;     std::tuple<A...> args;     auto operator()     { return std::apply(fn,args); }; };
It can simply be initialized as an aggregate now. And everything is publicly accessible.
